# Why does my AngularJS app not work when I add routing?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, I actually started today and I wanted to create a sample site for a company using AngularJS. My plan was to create a view for the products and a view for the about page.

This is my index.html code:

```
<!doctype html>


<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand"> {{ title }}</a>
        </div> <!-- navbar-header -->

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#/products">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what I have in my app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.title = "My company site"; 
});

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/products', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'productsController'
    }).
    when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
        controller: 'myCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/products'
    });
}]);

app.controller('productsController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'This will show my products page';
});

app.controller('aboutController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'This will show my about page';
});
```

Whenever I click on a link on my navbar the view for the clicked link doesn't get rendered. Also the title of the site is displayed like that `{{ title }}` on the browser. These problems started when I added the code for the routing. If I remove the code from the routing the title displays correctly. Also whenver I have the routing code on the site I get this error in my browser.
`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]` and it gives me a link to this [page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:unpr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2F$injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:43:7%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:40:270)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:41:1)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:41:86)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:39:234)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:39:358%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:39:135). I've visited the site and after checking everything the module seems to be loading fine only when I don't have the code for the routing in the app.js. So what am I doing wrong here? I'm looking at this for about an hour and I can't figure it out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565999/angular-js-routing-doesnt-work
This should help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Add the dependency. Worked for me.

Comment: Worked fine. I think the tutorials that I've been following didn't add this dependency. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Try this youtube channel. [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYxzS__5yYQmX2bItSRCqwiQZn5dIL1gt)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use `ngRoute`, which is a separate module and needs to be installed and included separately. The error page links to [another page](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider), which specifically tells you that `$routeProvider` is unknown in your current project. See the ngRoute page for installation instructions: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.

Most specifically:

> Then load the module in your application by adding it as a dependent module:
>
> ```
> angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading ngRoute in your app. To load it you should do something like this :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `var app = angular.module('myApp', []);` to `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);` you're missing the module injection.